# Can I express the travelling wave $V$ in terms of the travelling wave $U$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Suppose for some travelling wave solution  $u(x,t):=U(x-c^*t)$ 
$$
\lim_{\xi:=x-c^*t\to-\infty}U(\xi)=q,\quad \lim_{\xi\to\infty}U(\xi)=r
$$

for some unique $c=c^*<0$. Then this travelling wave moves from right to left.
In the $(u,u_\xi)$ phase plane this is a heteroclinic with $u_\xi>0$ and "arrows to the right".

Suppose there also exists a unique travelling wave $V(x-ct)$ with $c=-c^*>0$,  and
$$
\lim_{\nu:=x+c^*t\to\infty}V(\nu)=q,\quad\lim_{\nu\to -\infty}V(\nu)=r.
$$
This travelling wave should be a heteroclinic in the phase plane with $u_\xi<0$ and "arrows to the left".

---

My question is if it is possible to express $V$ in terms of $U$, maybe
$$
V=U(-\xi)=U(-x+c^*t)
$$
or would this be something completely different?

I am asking this because I would like to use sums of U and V and would like to express this in terms of U only.